# Sending api key in Authorization header to a REST Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a REST Web API which receives some `apiKey`. An example of a `GET` action of this Web API is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, string apiKey)
```

The only route that is defined in my Web API is:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now, there is a web client that uses this Web API and it sends the `apiKey` in the query string when doing `GET` requests.

I understand that it is better to send the `apiKey` in the Authorization header of the request.

Can someone show me how can I do a `GET` request and put that `apiKey` in the Authorization header and still land in the corect action method (I mean here the `Get` method above)?

Answer (score 4):

You can trick web api into thinking the Authorization header is parameter that came from the query string with a small message handler.

```
 public class ApiKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var routeData = request.GetRouteData();

            if (request.Headers.Authorization != null && !routeData.Values.ContainsKey("apikey"))
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("apikey",request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

This handler will grab the route data that has been extracted from the URI and if you pass an authorization header, it will take the parameter value and set it to be an `apikey` route parameter.

The authorization header needs to look something like

```
Authorization: apikey 12323434234234234
```

You can install the message handler by adding this link into your WebApiConfig.Register method.

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiKeyHandler());
```

As an aside, you can use a handler like this to actually validate the ApiKey.  This way you don't actually need to pass the apikey to your action method.  Simply return a 401 directly from your handler if the ApiKey is no good.

Comment: Hello, I understand what you mean.
I also understand that there is no need to have the apikey as parameter of each action method.

However, if I make a post request the apiKey is a hidden field in the form and it will not comeup in the Headers collection.